# Вывод заголовков записей в меню Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Добрый день. Нужно вывести заголовки записей в выпадающем меню на главной странице.

```
<ul class="ul2 item3" style="display: none;">
  <?php
  $my_posts = get_posts('numberposts=6&category=23');
  foreach ($my_posts as $post) :
  setup_postdata($post);
  ?>
   <li class="li2"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?>
   </a></li>    
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

В выпадающем меню появляются заголовки и можно даже перейти по ним, но на всей странице полностью отваливаются картинки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не забывайте про функцию `wp_reset_postdata();` после завершения цикла:

```
<?php

endforeach;
wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Нельзя использовать query_posts! Это внутренняя функция WordPress, с помощью которой выводится основной цикл. Используя эту функцию, вы ломаете основной цикл WordPress, в котором (предположу) и выводятся ваши картинки.

Используйте get_posts() или WP_Query, например:

```
$my_posts = get_posts( 'numberposts=6&category=23' );
```

Comment: Прошу прощения, допустил оплошность и скопипастил не тот код. В действительности я использую предложенную Вами функцию, но проблема не исчезла.

Comment: Без полного кода страницы ничего сказать нельзя. Какие картинки? Что значит "исчезли"? Что в консоли браузера?

Comment: Пропадают ссылки на картинки. В инспекторе все img отображаются <img src(unknow)>

Comment: Согласно правилам сообщества, вы должны создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Благодарю за уделенное внимание, проблему решил добавлением <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?> перед завершением цикла